# How to store enum states in CoreData in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, types, enums, enumeration

I searched a lot and find general answer like "**We generally store enumerations as strings or as integers into database**"

But what if I have an enum like this? How can I store this to Core Data?

```
enum UserItemType {
    case spring
    case summer
    case fall
    case winter
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `enum UserItemType` a rawValue and store the rawValue in into database. RawValue can be `Int` or `String` as you wish. Here is how:

```
enum UserItemType: Int {
```

To convert back to enum from rawValue, here's the code:

```
let userItemType = UserItemType(rawValue: valueFromDatabase)
```